# Correct input method for array of char?

Tags: c++, char

So I have this:

```
char *nume = new char[100];
```

What is the correct way to input into this char:

```
cin>>nume;
```

or

```
cin.getline(nume,100);
```

or something else?

Comment: I think the bigger question is *why* you must use `char*` and your own memory management?

Comment: Depends what you want to do.  The first option reads one word, the second reads a line up to 100 characters long.

Comment: Also note that [the `>>` operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2) and [`getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) does different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `cin >>` would only read the first word.
`cin.getline` reads characters until end of line or the specified delimiter.

So it depends on what you are trying to do, but it seems like you are preparing a 100-character buffer, so you are probably looking for `cin.getline`, unless you know there won't be spaces (reading a long hash) or you want to stop after the first word then you can go with `cin >>`